# Why is my material index not working on the other eye?

Tags: materials, workflow, compositing-nodes, render-passes

I have a robot with a monocle on one eye, and now I want to give his eyes a glare effect. So what I did is, I gave the emission material that is assigned to the eyes a pass index of 1. But after the render the eye behind the monocle wasn't detected. And the glare effect only worked on the open eye.

[image]

*What would be the best way to add glare to the eyes in this situation?*

Comment: Never really worked much with pass index, but the rendered pass is for the visible objects, not the ones behind them. If you want the pass of the eye either separate the monocle to another render layer and render it separately so you can still get the pass of the eye on a a separate layer, or assign the pass to the monocle itself instead.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yep actually moving monocle to another render layer worked perfectly, what a great idea. Thanks man! that worked the best out of all the things i tried.

Answer (score 1):

My best thought is make sure you have the blue part of the eye as a separate material index. Then use that as a factor for black and the original image. This will separate the eyes from the mesh.

Afterwards, you can use a glare node on the eyes. If you where to following this work flow make sure the threshold low.

Comment: Looks like you left your answer incomplete mid sentence. "*make sure the threshold*" ...what?

Comment: make sure the threshold is low